# Are these 2 nested functions (that bodies depend on top function arg) equivalent from the compiler's point of view?

Tags: haskell, optimization

I have some function `test` which has a signature like:

```
data D = D | C

test :: D -> ....
test d ... =
```

And I want to create with `let` some nested function which body is either body-A or body-B based on case analyze of the `d`. So, I can do it as:

```
let nestedFun p =
  case d of
      C -> case (ft, p) of
          (Just SM.FileTypeRegular, Just p1) | Just nm <- takeFileName (cs p1) -> S.member nm itemNames
          _ -> False
      D -> case (ft, p) of
          (Just SM.FileTypeRegular, Just p1) -> S.member (hash $ cs @_ @FilePath p1) itemHashes
          _ -> False
```

or as

```
let nestedFun p =
  case (ft, p) of
      (Just SM.FileTypeRegular, Just p1) -> case d of
          C | Just nm <- takeFileName (cs p1) ->
              S.member nm itemNames
          D ->
              S.member (hash $ cs @_ @FilePath p1) itemHashes
      _ -> False
```

In short, the difference is that the 1st version looks like Python's:

```
if isinstance(d, D):
  nestedFun = lambda p: ...
else:
  nestedFun = lambda p: ...
```

while the 2nd one is like:

```
  def nestedFun(p):
    if isinstance(d, D): ...
    else: ...
```

I will call this `nestedFun` on the big list of values so the question here is: Is the Haskell compiler/optimizer able to understand that both versions are the same and to reduce the 2nd one to the 1st one, so the case-analyze on `d` happens just once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GHC is able to -- the optimizer does consider case-of-case transformations to see if they enable other optimizations -- but not in a way that you can rely on. If you need this, I highly recommend performing that transformation by hand. In fact, for the case you describe here, I would go even farther, and make it clear that the `case` can happen before `p` is in scope:

```
nestedFunDmwit = case d of
    C -> \p -> case (ft, p) of ...
    D -> \p -> case (ft, p) of ...
```

The difference here is that `nestedFun` will re-evaluate the `case` each time it is applied to an argument, while `nestedFunDmwit` will evaluate the `case` just once. So, for example, `map (nestedFun x) [a, b, c]` would reliably evaluate the `case` just once; `map nestedFun [a, b, c]` would evaluate the `case` three times unless things line up just so for the optimizer; and `map nestedFunDmwit [a, b, c]` would reliably evaluate the `case` just once.

Comment: yep, I though about such way too. It answers to my question!